# How to send VGA data to monitor using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, vga

Is there a way to send vga(or any video data) to a display device via a VB application.

eg I have a desktop setup with my program running I click a play button and it send video data to a separate screen.

I have searched online and the best i can find is to get display information or to change resolution, neither of which I need.

Comment: Ummm. you don't send 'VGA data'. You write to a graphics device and that'll handle converting the pixel data into whatever format the video output device requires. beyond that, VGA is an analog video spec. there is no 'data'. there's just voltage levels.

Comment: If you want to play a video try the Windows Media Player COM component.

Comment: The media player COM component looks as if it will do the basic job of displaying media, but eventually I'll need it to display on a separate display device which I'll need to investigate further

Answer (score -1):

```
'for secondary screen 
'frmplayer contain your videoplayer
if system.windows.form.screen.allscreen.count>1 then
    frmplayer.left=system.windows.form.screen.allscreen(1).bound.left
end if
```